# Speed up mobile safari font-face rendering?

Tags: uiwebview, rendering, mobile-safari, font-face, performance

i render customs fonts in a webview on the iPad. rendering works and the fonts get displayed as they should. but, the rendering is slow. so everything is on my pages loads up quickly, except for the font-face. any idea how i can speed up things?

thanks

Comment: Is the problem that the custom font isn't actually displaying fast enough or that the text isn't displayed at all until the font file has loaded?

Comment: nothing gets displayed until the whole font loads. so it's often about 1sec..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options you have to optimise your font-face rules.  By using a `data: url` you can use the font inline by encoding in base64. For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Font";
    src: url("data:font/opentype;base64,[base-encoded font here]");
}
```

There are some other useful performance considerations and approaches outlined [in this article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/13/font-face-and-performance/) from 2009.

Comment: Good luck. Hope you crack the problem.